Storing data from HTML widget data variable to attribute form in QGIS
How to link HTML widget form data variable to attribute form variables in QGIS. Here I am creating Radio button using HTML widget and the data should be transferred to attribute table

I assume HTML widgets are only intended for display (i.e. pie charts, etc.).
Maybe you can provide an Qt designer UI-file if you want to use Radio buttons.
